# WebLogic silent install JAR throws illegal argument error

Tags: java, oracle-linux, weblogic

I am trying to install WebLogic 10.3.6 on Oracle Linux using silent mode. When I run the below command it throws illegal argument. It does not even read the response file. Does anyone know the reason?

```
#java -jar wls1036_generic.jar -silent -responseFile /scratch/u01/wl.rsp

Illegal argument: -silent
Illegal argument: -responseFile
Illegal argument: /scratch/u01/wl.rsp
Unable to instantiate GUI, defaulting to console mode.
Extracting 0%.....................................^C
```

Both JAVA_HOME and PATH variable are set. Here is the Java version-

```
# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line parameters you're using don't seem to be correct (hence the "Illegal argument" errors). According to the [WebLogic installation guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/doc.1211/e24492/silent.htm), the command should be of the form:

```
java -jar file_name.jar -mode=silent -silent_xml=path_to_silent.xml
```

In your case then,

```
java -jar wls1036_generic.jar -mode=silent -silent_xml=/scratch/u01/wl.rsp
```

Comment: Oh.. i was referencing [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/OUIRF/silent.htm#OUIRF334) and [this](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/weblogic-silent-installation-12c). Maybe they changed it for newer version. But do you know how to point to the inventory location using the above?